# How prevent angular auto trim for fields?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, trim

Is there any way prevent angular from auto trim for fields in the whole application? I know that I can prevent it for specified field using ngTrim directive, but it doesn't look good add this directive to all text fields in the application, is there any way do it for all fields in the angular module?
Here is code, if you add add spaces in the begin of input they will not appear in label:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      {{field}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="field">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your code? Difficult to tell what you're referring to.

Comment: Why can not trim? Maybe there is a better solution than simply disable `ngTrim`.

Comment: Looking at the code (1.3.15) there seems to be no way - do a search for ngTrim! I did not expect this!

Comment: because fields in database contains spaces in the beginning, and need compare them.

Comment: You can trim the databases fields for comparison?

Comment: trim the databases fields is not an option, because I need do it in too many places, it is even worse then added to all fields ng-trim="false"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend [input[text]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) directive, the code below will automatically change the value of the attribute `ngTrim` to `false`:

```
.directive('input', function($compile){
    // Runs during compile
    return {
      link(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        if (iElement.attr('type') === 'text') {
          iAttrs.$set('ngTrim', "false");
        }
      }
    };
});
```

Reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-text-input-directive</title>
  

  <script src="https://docs.angularjs.org/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="textInputExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('textInputExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.example = {
        text: 'guest'
      };
    }])
    .directive('input', function($compile){
        // Runs during compile
        return {
          link(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            if (iElement.attr('type') === 'text') {
              iAttrs.$set('ngTrim', "false");
            }
          }
        };
    });
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Single word:
    <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="example.text" required>
  </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.pattern">
      Single word only!</span>
  </div>
  <tt>text = {{example.text}} - 3</tt><br/>
  <tt>text = {{example.text.length}} - 3</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**How it works**

1. You can bind multiple directives to the same html element and they can share the same `$scope` and `$attributes`.
2. `iAttrs.$set('ngTrim', "false");` is updating the attribute `ng-trim`. You can't do this using normal dom manipulation because the dom is already compiled (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)
3. Calling `iAttrs.$set` will trigger updates on all directives, so it will override the original `ng-trim` attribute value.

Comment: this is not valid js code, but I get your idea and try to implement it.

Comment: I was able to run this code, but I still don't understand how it is possible, but it is not a question, so your answer is correct.

Comment: I edited my answer, basically as all directives are sharing the same scope, changing any property will reflect in all directives.

Comment: Is there any way use it for angular earlier than 1.3.0?

Comment: I already get answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557490/how-prevent-angular-version-earlier-than-1-3-0-auto-trim-for-fields/30557607#30557607

Answer (score 2):

Another way to extend the `input` directive (or any directive/service, for that matter) is by using a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator):

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('inputDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0],
        link = directive.link;

    link.post = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('ngTrim', 'false');
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RqMEu46pihb2UCXUpSRt?p=preview)

I personally prefer this approach because it allows me to execute the directive's original code, if needed. In this particular case that isn't necessary because the `input` directive has no link function, so you can simply provide your own without worrying about breaking anything.

Comment: Is there any way use it for angular earlier than 1.3.0?

Comment: I already get answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557490/how-prevent-angular-version-earlier-than-1-3-0-auto-trim-for-fields/30557607#30557607