# How to make angular ui-grid filter support the users typing in spaces?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

By default, angular calls trim on inputs.  `ng-trim` was added so that this feature could be disabled.  I have a business requirement to filter rows where a column contains a space (" ") if that is what a user types in.  However, I don't see any way using `gridOptions` to set `ng-trim`.  How can I allow spaces in the filter to be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

u can disable it via ng-trim attribute

```
<input type="text"
   ng-model="string"
   [name="string"]
   [required="string"]
   [ng-required="string"]
   [ng-minlength="number"]
   [ng-maxlength="number"]
   [pattern="string"]
   [ng-pattern="string"]
   [ng-change="string"]
   [ng-trim="boolean"]>  < --- thats what u need
```

ngTrim
(optional)
boolean 
If set to false Angular will not automatically trim the input. This parameter is ignored for input[type=password] controls, which will never trim the input.
(default: true)
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Comment: I agree with you that `ng-trim` is the way to make this work.  I just don't know how to tell `ui-grid` to set that.  The boxes are generated via `ui-grid`.

Comment: override `cellTemplate` for displaying and `editableCellTemplate` for editing in `columnDefs`

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a decorator for the compile function to override global auto-trim feature as following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557490/how-prevent-angular-version-earlier-than-1-3-0-auto-trim-for-fields/30557607#30557607).